# iOS located photos without Wi-Fi/cell network

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, photos, geolocation

Last week I was in another country and had no connection to internet nor to my operator. I had the Airplane mode turned on the whole time and took a lot of photos. Yesterday I came back home and connected again to Wi-Fi. All the photos I took are located in the exact same streets/city/country they've been taken.

How is this possible? How does iOS knows where I was if I didn't have any connection till yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone has GPS. This doesn't require Wi-Fi or cellular towers and isn't disabled when you turn on Airplane mode.

Comment: yeah, but info was added to photos only when connected to internet not before

Comment: @user129887 The EXIF data was still written with the longitude and latitude without network connectivity, but it didn't know what this related to in terms of city or have the ability to open a map without the Internet.

Comment: wow. thanks for clearing out my doubts about it ;)